# Rails 4 has_many associations w/Postgres: query table A for all records that actually have B, C, and D

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

Given a model with multiple `has_many` associations like this:

```
class Route < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :flights
  has_many :deals
  has_many :ratings
  ...
end
```

Given a scenario where not all routes actually have all 3, is there an easy way to find the number of routes that *do* have all 3?

Based on other SO questions I have tried this:
`scope :active, -> { joins(:ratings).joins(:deals).joins(:flights)`. Then I call `Route.active.count` in my console but the process just hangs. These tables are pretty large so I'm assuming it has something to do with it. Flights has 2,037,031 rows; Deals has 659,804 rows; and Ratings has 141,879.

Is there a faster/better way to get to the number I need (number of routes that have flights, deals, and ratings)?

**EDIT**

Here is the relevant schema info:

```
  create_table "routes", force: true do |t|
    t.integer  "from_id"
    t.integer  "to_id"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  add_index "routes", ["from_id"], name: "index_routes_on_from_id", using: :btree
  add_index "routes", ["to_id"], name: "index_routes_on_to_id", using: :btree

  create_table "ratings", force: true do |t|
    # various columns...
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.integer  "route_id"
  end

  add_index "ratings", ["route_id"], name: "index_ratings_on_route_id", using: :btree

  create_table "flights", force: true do |t|
    t.integer  "airline_id"
    t.integer  "route_id"
    # various columns...
  end

  add_index "flights", ["airline_id"], name: "index_flights_on_airline_id", using: :btree
  add_index "flights", ["route_id"], name: "index_flights_on_route_id", using: :btree

  create_table "deals", force: true do |t|
    t.integer  "route_id"
    # various columns...
  end

  add_index "deals", ["route_id"], name: "index_deals_on_route_id", using: :btree
```

**EDIT**

I added boolean attributes to the Routes table of `flightless` and `ratingless` to help keep easier track after an import of whether the Route has any flights or ratings. After doing that, I've tried a few different queries and get different counts:

```
[7] pry(main)> Route.where(flightless: false, ratingless: false).includes(:deals).count
=> 19415
[8] pry(main)> Route.where(flightless: false, ratingless: false).joins(:deals).distinct.count
=> 10243
[9] pry(main)> Route.where(flightless: false, ratingless: false).joins(:deals).count
=> 378737
```

The query on line 8 produces the same result as Nic's pure SQL suggestion in the first answer below. I think I understand why the query on line 9 returns way more than could possible be correct (each route is duplicated for every resource it gets joined to) but I don't understand the difference between `joins` and `includes` well enough to tell why `joins...distinct` produces a different answer than `includes` here.

Comment: Those numbers aren't too big. but maybe you need to check on your indexes. It would be helpful if you could show us the schema.rb for those tables.

Comment: @pepito2k sure thing! added the schema.rb for the routes, flights, ratings, and deals tables

Comment: Does this `includes(:flights, :deals, :ratings)` changes anything?

Comment: @Pavan I tried `Route.includes(:deals, :ratings, :flights).count` in the console and it returned 514,806 which can't be correct because that's the same as `Route.count` and I'm very sure that not all routes have all 3

Comment: Can you get the correct count in `psql` using pure SQL? You could always do a view in the DB as that will give you better performance on large queries, then create  model in the DB for the view.

Comment: Normally `Route.joins(:deals, :ratings, :flights).distinct.count` should get you what you want. But I am not sure it's feasible performance wise in your case.

Answer (score 1):

Using `joins` as well as `includes` will generate a cartesian product which will require some memory and depending on available resources can make the server unresponsive. Since you're after count and not the actual records, it should be enough to check for their existence, albeit probably at the expense of more calculations:

```
Route.where('EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM ratings WHERE routes.id = ratings.route_id) 
    AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM deals WHERE routes.id = deals.route_id) 
    AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM flights WHERE routes.id = flights.route_id)').count
```

Although this mostly is raw SQL, it will return a proper `ActiveRecord::Relation` when `count` is skipped. This allows using it for on-demand loading of models like in `find_in_batches`.

This most probably can be rewritten using Arel to be more Rails way, but at this point I'm curious whether it actually gets you the proper result.

**EDIT**:

Or you could use

```
Route.joins(:ratings).joins(:deals).joins(:flights).distinct.count
```

It will return the correct count but will produce an intermediary cartesian product which it will then reduce with `distinct`. I would be curious to know what is the performance difference between these two approaches.

Comment: Thank you! This produces 10243, which seems reasonable. However, I added a couple boolean columns to help make the query faster (see the last edit to my question) and am getting different counts for 3 different queries. One of them, however, also comes out with 10243. Do you mind taking a look at that ?

Comment: Actually using `distinct` the way you did should also work for your initial query `Route.joins(:ratings).joins(:deals).joins(:flights).distinct.count` which would be a lot simpler and cleaner thatn my SQL example.

Comment: `joins` generates `INNER JOIN` statement which produces the cartesian result. Records of the first table get returned as many times as there are associated records in the referenced tables. Your query begins with `select routes.*` so you get pure duplicates. `distinct` only returns records with unique field sets. Should you `include` any fields from referenced tables, `distinct` would not work to your purpose. `include` adds fields from a referenced table to the resultset, like `select routes.*, ratings.*`. It is useful for fetching dependencies along with the parent in one go.

Comment: It looks like the original query isn't an option because of the performance hit. I don't see any other choice at this point than to start the query with these boolean columns and then only join `deals` with `.distinct`

Comment: Actually your approach with cached state is very valid. Take a look at the [counter_cache association option in Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#counter-cache).